# <IndexUserFields> fields haven't been indexed

Tags: umbraco

I'm working on an Umbraco project.
I'm using a StandardAnalyzer indexer and I've just added an ArabicAnalyzer indexer.

The fields under `<IndexUserFields>` haven't been indexed.

part of my ExamineIndex.config file:

```
<IndexSet SetName="ArabicIndexSet" IndexPath="~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/Arabic/" >

 <IndexAttributeFields>
  <add Name="id" />
  <add Name="sortOrder"/>
  <add Name="nodeName"  EnableSorting="true"/>
 </IndexAttributeFields>

 <IndexUserFields>
  <add Name="_AllContents"/>
  <add Name="cityName"/>
  <add Name="countryName"/>
 </IndexUserFields>

 <IncludeNodeTypes>
  <add Name="Country" />
  <add Name="DestinationInfoTopic" />
  <add Name="Article" />
 </IncludeNodeTypes>

 </IndexSet>
```

All `<IndexAttributeFields>` fields are indexed, but `<IndexUserFields>` aren't, BTW the same fields are indexed using StandardAnalyzer.

Do I need to do something extra in order to index these fields?

Comment: "All fields are indexed, but aren't"?  Kinda poetic, but I have no idea what you actually mean.  Can you describe the problem more clearly?  What, exactly, have you observed to indicate that the fields are not indexed correctly?

Comment: @femtoRgon The XML tags were not escaped, and so were invisible. The question should make more sense now.

Comment: Hah! Good catch, @legoscia.  Makes much more sense.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice the XML wasn't escaped, do you guys have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of digging finally I found an answer to my problem.

Due to our ArabicAnalyzer usage we must add the indexSet name to the Indexer provider:

```
<add name="ArabicIndexer" 
type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
supportUnpublished="false"
supportProtected="false"
interval="15"
analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR.ArabicAnalyzer, Lucene.Net.Contrib.Analyzers"
indexSet="ArabicIndexSet" />
```